# Economics Textbook Help

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The problem I am working through deals with taking the derivative of $N^*$ with respect to tau:
[image]

I have the answer but can not seem to arrive at it.

Comment: Edit your post so the question can be seen without following the link.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. It is generally helpful to us if you post whatever attempts you've made at the problem. Did you try it first?

Comment: Is part of the question missing?

Answer (score 1):

$N^* = \left(1+\frac {\theta}{1-\alpha} + \frac {\theta\alpha\beta\delta}{(1-\alpha)(1-\tau)(1-\beta - \delta\beta)}\right)^{-1}\\
\frac {dN^*}{d\tau} = -\left(1+\frac {\theta}{1-\alpha} + \frac {\theta\alpha\beta\delta}{(1-\alpha)(1-\tau)(1-\beta - \delta\beta)}\right)^{-2}\left(\frac {\theta\alpha\beta\delta}{(1-\alpha)(1-\tau)^2(1-\beta - \delta\beta)}\right)$

Is there a format that you are looking for?

Comment: Times the derivative of $(1-\tau)$, i.e.: a "-" is missing.

Comment: That is not actually the minus sign that I missed, but I did indeed miss a minus sign.